# tensorflow output coordinates

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, coordinate-systems

i have the following task: i'm supposed to find the coordinates of an targetpoint. The features that are given, are the distances from anchors to that targetpoint. See img 1 [distances from anchors to target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JklPE.png)

I planned to create a simple neural network first just with input and output layer. The cost-function i try to minimize is: correct_coordinate - mean of square(summed_up_distances*weights).
But now i'm kind of stuck in how to model the neural network, so that i'm outputting coordinates [x,y], as the current model would just output a single value. See img 2 [current model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZeAw.png)

Right now I would than just train 2 neural networks. One that outputs the x-value, and one that outputs the y-value. 
I'm just not sure if that is the best practice with tensorflow.

So I would like to know, how would you model the NN with tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the network with 2 nodes in the output layer. there is no need to train 2 neural networks for the same task.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realized that this is possible, since I havent understand the concept of NN completely.